¿Cómo puedo hacer un Slider de Material UI que sea de solo lectura?
Quiero ajustar un Slider de Material UI solo para que muestre datos y no se puede editar o mover el Slider, sin deshabilitarlo porque pierde los estilos, he intentado lo siguiente pero no funciona:
        <Slider
          aria-label="Default"
          valueLabelDisplay="auto"
          min={0}
          max={12}
          marks={marks}
          onChange={(e) => handleChange(e, 0)}
          sx={{ color: "#D80027" }}
          slotProps={{input: {readOnly}}}
        />


has intentado averiguar por que tu script no funciona??? de paso te recomiendo hacer el [tour]
